# interpreting propensity score results in stratification method in SAS

Tags: sas

I am using propensity score stratification method. I got some output but can't interpret. I am looking for a source how to interpret those results.

I have divided PS scores into 5 groups and got this output at the end after running some codes

```
obs =1
type =0
freq =10 sum_wt = 1010988.4 sum_diff= 0.0015572 mean-diff= 0.0015572 SE-diff= 0.0000994551
```

I know that frequency column stands for 2*5(number of groups), mean diff is equal to sum diff and SE diff is the sq rt of 1-sum of weights

Does it say that ranking PS scores into 5 groups is an appropriate approach ? Which of above criteria I should use for final decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your output is just stating the distribution within the groups. You evaluate whether or not propensity score matching, in your case stratified matching, works by looking at the absolute standardized differences of the variables pre vs post-matching.

[Here](https://www.gastrojournal.org/article/S0016-5085(18)34813-3/abstract) is a peer reviewed paper my colleagues and I published that incorporates propensity score matching. There is some details in the methodology section that I wrote which should answer your question on how to evaluate if your approach is working.